# Integrate elasticSearch with EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, elasticsearch

I have to implement a tool which allows me to search in my database. So, I have been looking for something and I met with with elasticSearch. It supposed this tool works fine with eclipselink, but I could not find any good tutorial or documentation about how to integrate these tools.

Please, If you can help me. I will be grateful. Thanks

Sarang

Answer (score 1):

There probably isn't a tutorial for integrating EclipseLink with ElasticSearch.  You'll need to develop your own.

Start with the [ElasticSearch Java API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/java-api/).

Some people will use [Elastic as a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636508/elasticsearch-as-a-database). If you still have a database, then you'll need to keep the ES index up to date with the database.  You'll need to hook into the insert/update commands (if possible) and re-index objects as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible I would recommend you use Hibernate instead of eclipselink as a JPA implementation.

> Why not use Elasticsearch directly: The #1 reason is that Hibernate
>   Search integrates perfectly with Hibernate ORM. All changes done to
>   your objects will trigger the necessary index changes transparently.
>   https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.6/reference/en-US/html/ch11.html

I also found this tutorial very informative:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufaI51o_7WI